# Are these 2 Java exam questions incorrect?

Tags: java, interface, doubly-linked-list

I recently did an exam related to Java that had 2 questions that in my opinion were wrong. I was hoping some of you could help me out.

The questions are:

1)

```
public class Cell {
    public Cell(){
    }
    public char content; //The character in this cell.
    public Cell next;  // Pointer to the cell to the right of this one.
    public Cell prev;  // Pointer to the cell to the left of this one.
}

// The following method is supposed to move one node to the right in a 
// doubly linked list of Cells but it contains a flaw.
// The global variable 'currentCell' is a pointer to a Cell in the list.

public void moveRight(){
    if (currentCell.next == null){
        Cell newCell = new Cell();
        newCell.content = '';
        newCell.next = null;
        newCell.prev = currentCell;
        currentCell.next = newCell;
        currentCell = currentCell.next;
     }
 }
```

> True or False: If 'currentCell' is at the head of the list this moveRight()
> method will perform its duties correctly.

For me, this question is False, as the moveRight method will not do anything because currentCell.next is NOT null when the pointer is at the head of the list. Its duties (move to the right) will not be successful.
I would like to know what the community thinks, because according to the exam this should be True?

2.

> True or False: An interface contains method declarations as well as implementations.

I believe this should be True. As stated by Oracle (2021), “An interface declaration can contain method signatures, default methods, static methods, and constant definitions. The only methods that have implementations are default and static methods.”

Yet, the exam stated that the correct answer is False.

I hope someone could clarify this further for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Whether the `currentCell.next` is null or not depends on whether the pointer points to the last node or not. As for the second question, it’s true IMO. You can always ask these questions to Oracle if you’re unclear about the verbiage.

Comment: I think the answer to question 2 was technically `False` for older versions of java. From what I remember, default implementations in interfaces are a relatively new feature

Comment: It's odd that the exam gave an answer of True after explicitly saying that the method has a flaw.

Comment: @byxor. Since 2014 (Java 8)

Comment: @tgdavies coder's 101: read the requirements. If the requirement is for method to work only under specific conditions, then they are fulfilled. Not setting such stupid requirements is _architect's_ 101, taught on year 3.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @greg-449 Okay, so I can just duplicate posts? I think my argumentation is valid. I should have avoided answering the questions beforehand. Please tell me the steps to take next so that I can rephrase the question in the future such that people actually can upvote their 'correct' answer. Thank you

Comment: Instead of reposting, you could just edit the question to not include the answers.

Comment: @cigien. That would render all the current replies invalid, making the post a huge mess. No problem, we leave it like this then. Will use other platforms for further clarification. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can conclude that the questions are not clear and shouldn't be the standard for an exam.
Question 1 is vague and its unclear what is meant exactly.
For question 2 it is safe to state that since 2014 the correct answer should be True.

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

The problem with the method is not about the `!= null` check: that will be true when `currentCell` is the last element of the list, and in that case there will be nothing to move (it cannot be moved right).

2.

The question should technically be True for newer versions of Java (after 2014 default methods implementation in Java 8), but (personally) I think the question was more about the essence of interfaces, that are used typically to **abstract away from implementations**, providing just method declarations.

Comment: The only time it performs its duties correctly, is when currentCell points to the tail. It creates a new Cell, adds it to the end of the list and moves towards it, thus moving to the right. You stating True is correct here? I don't understand it still ))

Comment: There is a case where pointing to head works, that is when the head is the tail. However, the bug in the code is that the last line inside the if should be moved under the if.

Comment: @jxh Yes. That would fix the bug, but still leaves me convinced the answer to the question itself should be **false**

Comment: It isn't clear if the question pointed out the existence of the flaw in order for it to be fixed, and subsequent questions would be about the fixed code.